# Problem with modbus communication between two arduinos when writing more than 27 registers

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, rs485, modbus

I have the following problem:
I want send 200 registers from a modbus master to a slave. Both are arduinos.
I can't send more than 27 registers. When I send more i get the Errorcode `255` which means `timeout`. I know that the modbus message is limited to 253 bytes (256 bytes - server address (1 byte) - CRC  (2 bytes)). Listed here: [MODBUS APPLICATION PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION page.5](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf)

**My setup:**

- I use two Arduino Mega 2560. One as a master and the other as the slave. If that works I want to use more than one slave. They are connected via Serial1 master TX1 (pin18) to slave RX1 (pin19) and master RX1 (pin19) to slave TX1 (pin18).
- The modbus library I'm using is [ModbusRtu.h](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino) from smarmengol.
- Because i want to ultimately communicate with more than one slave device I use RS-485. To send the message as a broadcasat but thats not relevant now because first I want to send to one slave to test it out.

I know that the array is much bigger as the registers I want to send. Thats because I wanted to know when the the timeout happens. Sending 27 registers works fine and the slave recieves all of the 27. But when sending more than 27 registers I get the timeout and nothing will be send.

**Master code**

```c
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#include "ModbusRtu.h"

#define Timeout 150
#define QUERYINTERVALL 50

/* Defined the buffersize as stated in 
 * C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBAPI.h
*/

modbus_t telegram;

// Test sending large array
uint16_t sendLargeArray[200] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
                                18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
                                33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
                                48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
                                63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77,
                                78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92,
                                93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
                                106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117,
                                118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
                                130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141,
                                142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153,
                                154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,
                                166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
                                178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189,
                                190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199};

Modbus master;

void dataSend();

void setup()
{

 /**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
    master = Modbus(0, 1, 8); // this is master with RS-485 config
    master.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2);
    master.setTimeOut(Timeout);
    Serial.begin(9600); // setup Serial for USB debugging
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t error = master.getLastError(); //get errorcode
    uint8_t state = master.getState();     // get state from master 0 = idle 1 = waiting

    dataSend(); // function for sending array

    // Error Code
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.print(error);
    Serial.println();

    // Print master state
    Serial.print("Master State: ");
    Serial.print(state);
    Serial.println();
}

void dataSend()
{
    uint8_t slaveId;
    uint8_t u8state;
    unsigned long u32wait;
    slaveId = 1;
    u32wait = millis() + QUERYINTERVALL;
    bool staywhile = true;

    // telegram for sending sendLargeArray
    telegram.u8id = 1;
    telegram.u8fct = 16;
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 0;
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 28; // 27 or less works fine
    telegram.au16reg = sendLargeArray;
    u8state = 0;

    // Master broadcasts data
    while (staywhile)
    {
        switch (u8state)
        {
        case 0:
            if (millis() > u32wait)
                u8state++; // wait state
            break;
        case 1:
            master.query(telegram); // send query (only once)
            u8state++;
        case 2:
            master.poll(); // check incoming messages
            if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE)
            {
                u8state = 0;
                u32wait = millis() + QUERYINTERVALL;
                staywhile = false;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Slave code**

```c
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#include "ModbusRtu.h"

/* Defined the buffersize as stated in 
     * C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBAPI.h
    */

// data array for modbus network sharing

uint16_t recieveLargeArray[200] = {};

 /**
  *  Modbus object declaration
  *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
  *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
  *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
  *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus slave(1, 1, 8); // this is slave @1 and RS-485

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  slave.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2); // baud-rate at 9600
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t error = slave.getLastError();
  slave.poll(recieveLargeArray, 28); // receiving 27 or less registers works fine

  // print every 5th element of the recieved array
  // no spamming console that way
  Serial.print("Recieve: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i += 5)
  {
    Serial.print(recieveLargeArray[i]);
    Serial.print(",");
  }
  // Error Code
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Error code: ");
  Serial.print(error);
  Serial.println();

  memset(recieveLargeArray, 0, 200 * sizeof(uint16_t)); // recieveLargeArray = {}

}
```

**Questions**

- Does anyone know why I cant send more than 27 registers?
- Did anyone made a simillar project and can share the code?
- Has anyone a fix for that?

Help is very appreciated.

Cheers ueberBrot

[Link issuepage on ModbusRTU.h GitHub](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/issues/40)

**Edit**

- Forgot to mention that I increased the buffer size inside the `ModbusRTU.h` library aswell. I did it like that `#define MAX_BUFFER 256` as mentioned in [this comment from Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/57819/50966)
- Changed the define location of `#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256` in both sketches to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did change the `MAX_BUFFER` inside `ModbusRTU.h` from 64 to 256. As you stated before in there its only the size for the used array. What I also did was move the `#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256` inside both my sketches to the top. That did nothing, After that I found a way to increase the RX and TX buffer size with the help of [this post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=399751.msg2749597#msg2749597). I changed it from 64 to 256. maybe I could have changed those with a `#define` in my sketches aswell?.

Now I can send a max of 59 registers at once. Im not sure why I cant send more because the max should be 123 registers at once and the buffer is 256 bytes so  123 registers x 2 bytes = 246 is enough space in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In ModbusRtu.h:

`#define MAX_BUFFER 64 //!< maximum size for the communication buffer in bytes`

27*2=54 bytes for registers and 10 for header and crc.

Change the MAX_BUFFER define. On Mega you have enough RAM.

btw: RS485 doesn't imply mandatory use of Modbus. You could use your own protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Juraj.
Oh sorry forget to mention that in the original post. After I increased the Arduino buffer size to 256 byte I did the same inside the `ModbusRTU.h` library `#define MAX_BUFFER 256 ` . So thats not the problem.
Using my own protocol what do you mean by that? I dont have a clue how to do that so Im guessing its either not in my skillrange or I simply dont know where to begin. Can you explain or point me to an example? That I could use for my ultimate goal a master with many slaves?
Cheers ueberBrot

Comment: if it allows only 27 registers, then it didn't apply. what "Arduino buffer"?

Comment: In the file `***\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBAPI.h` the `SERIAL BUFFER SIZE` (Arduino buffer) is defined from line 77 to 86. If the buffer is not defined like I did in my sketches `#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256` it has two default values 16 or 64 byte dependening of the Arduino RAM. Or is this wrong?

Comment: not wrong, but not needed. The Serial buffer is really a 'buffer'. If full, write() waits a little until there is space (bytes are send out continuously). The buffer in ModbusRtu.h is not a real buffer, it is an array to build the complete message.

Comment: Ah ok thought it may be connected to my problem thats why I increased it. If the change I did inside the library did not apply how is that? Do you have a clue?

Comment: did you change the define inside ModbusRtu.h? in your sketch it is too late.